# Want to re-instate windows as primary OS

Tags: boot, partitioning

I want to move ubuntu off an old drive so I repartitioned it and made windows one partition (I was dual-booting). The problem I have is that I have no idea how to boot into windows after ubuntu had already rewrote the boot priority. Can somebody tell me how to reset windows as the default OS?

Comment: Why do you expect us to know that? >:-D We are Ubuntu users for a reason. Oh and try `fixmbr` from a Windows command line.

Comment: I'm kinda a noob so I need instructions :( All I can see from booting is No such partition, grub rescue>

Comment: And it's not that I'm against ubuntu, I plan to install it on its own drive separate from windows :)

Comment: @user138321 insert windows installation disc and from there you "repair" your system by going to command line and typing "fixmbr". In general... I remember this from my WIN98 days ;)

Comment: A slight problem, I lost mine D:

Comment: Disregard this question, solved by claimed duplicate :) Sorry for the duplicate, I panicked